# Must be superuser to create this extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, postgis

In PostgreSQL on heroku I need to add extension of PostGIS.
For it I run

```
heroku pg:psql
```

When I run

```
looks-test::DATABASE=> create extension postgis;
```

It gives error

```
ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "postgis"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

Comment: I guess that would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723100/why-can-only-a-superuser-create-extension-hstore-but-not-on-heroku

Comment: It related to HSTORE not postgis

Comment: You're right, but the error is also related to insufficient permissions on heroku

Comment: See the manual. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-extensions-postgis-full-text-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the database plan you're trying to create the postgis extension?
Postgis is only available for production databases, because hobby ones are sharing the same server with several other ones, and postgis is usually very CPU-bound, which would impact the performance of all other customer databases.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgis

> The beta is available on all Production tier databases and currently supports PostGIS version 2.0. It is not available on the Dev or Basic Hobby tier plans.