# Cannot run migrations when postgres extension added in rails 5 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to use pg_trgm extension of Postgres for searching using query

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE location like '%new%' ORDER BY location DESC;
```

Since Postgres already don't have pg_trgm I need to execute a command to install it. So my migration to do so is

```
class Addtrigramindexlocationtousers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    reversible do |direction|
        direction.up {
            execute %{
                CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
                CREATE INDEX index_users_trigram_on_location ON users USING gin (location gin_trgm_ops);
            }
        }
        direction.down {
            execute %{
                DROP INDEX index_users_trigram_on_location;
            }           
        }
    end
  end
end
```

So when I run this migration it is giving me this error:

```
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "pg_trgm"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
: 
                DROP INDEX index_users_on_location;
                CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
                CREATE INDEX index_users_trigram_on_location ON users USING gin (location gin_trgm_ops);
```

This works if I manually enter to database and execute the command but I need to run it from migration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When enabling extensions its a good idea to create a separate migration as it makes it much easier to troubleshoot:

```
class EnableTrigramIndexLocationExtension < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    enable_extension "pg_trgm"
  end
end
```

> Loading an extension requires the same privileges that would be
>   required to create its component objects. For most extensions this
>   means superuser or database owner privileges are needed. The user who
>   runs CREATE EXTENSION becomes the owner of the extension for purposes
>   of later privilege checks, as well as the owner of any objects created
>   by the extension's script.

The simplest way to solve this is by using `ALTER ROLE myapp SUPERUSER;` which is not a very secure solution but works for development. For a production server you should instead use [PostgreSQL Extension Whitelisting](https://github.com/dimitri/pgextwlist).

When generating migrations make sure to use either snakecase or camelcase to make the name readable `rails g migration AddTrigramIndexLocationToUsers` or `rails g migration add_trigram_index_location_to_users`.

```
class AddTrigramIndexLocationToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    execute %{ 
      CREATE INDEX index_users_trigram_on_location ON users USING gin (location gin_trgm_ops); 
    }
  end

  def down
    remove_index :users, :index_users_trigram_on_location
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you but it is still complaining that I must be super user to create this extension. I created database using $ createuser --createdb --login -P myapp I think something is missing there so it will work successfully

Comment: Is that the same user that you are using to connect rails?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723100/why-can-only-a-superuser-create-extension-hstore-but-not-on-heroku

Comment: Either [grant the user superuser privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-grant.html) or use [PostgreSQL Extension Whitelisting](https://github.com/dimitri/pgextwlist)

Comment: Successfully solved using ALTER ROLE myapp SUPERUSER; Thanks. :)

Comment: Just beware that adding the SUPERUSER role to the user connected to your web app is very insecure as it would let an SQL injection attack drop every schema on the database.

Comment: I did that on my development machine only. I tried to run the migration in heroku. It migrated without asking for privileges. I think it is safe then.

Comment: Yes Heroku uses whitelisting to let you install extensions.

Comment: In my structure.sql file I saw this line : CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm WITH SCHEMA public;
does this public means it is risky now? But on other lines on other extensions I see pg_catloge: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;

Comment: Not really: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-schemas.html